# Python Cramers' V Handling Missing Values & Date Fields

Tags: python, data-science, correlation, static-analysis, chi-squared

I'm working on association analysis on my dataset that consist majorly of categorical features and I'm using Cramers' V and Theils U statistical measures for showcasing the association metrics.

I have 2 questions related to same :

1. If there are some missing values in some of the columns in my dataset, how should I handle them while calculation Cramers' V and theils u metrics. Shall i replace missing value with some dummy value ? Note : I'm using python's dython library for calculation of both the metrics.

   dython.nominal.cramers_v(data[field1],data[field2]) and dython.nominal.theils_u(data[field1],data[field2])
2. If I have a column name like "Task Creation Date" that consist of datetime values. How can I include this field as part of my association analysis ? Does Cramers' V and Theils U consider date values as input ? or some conversion is required ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As for your two questions:

1. This is really up to you, there's no right and wrong here.
2. Apparently, Dython isn't supporting dates, while it should. I logged it as a bug on the library's GitHub page ([here](https://github.com/shakedzy/dython/issues/76)).

**EDIT:** Dython supports datetime as of version 0.6.6